# How to get a nice stack view in radare2?

Tags: radare2

This is the stack view that I'm getting in radare2 after entering the visual panel mode:

[image]

This is the view from immunity debugger:

[image]

How can I get a view similar to immunity debugger in radare2?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have several ways to print the stack. The specific way that you're searching for is called Stack Telescoping and you can print it like this:

```
pxr @ esp
```

Use `sp`, `esp`, and `rsp` according to your system.

`pxr` stands for **P**rint he**X**adecimal **R**eferences, you can see its description by using `px?`:

```
[0x7f8a672ee4]> px?
<...truncated...>
pxr[j]            show words with references to flags and code
```

Here are some other options to print the stack using radare2:

- `pxa @ rsp` - to show annotated hexdump
- `pxw @ rsp` - to show hexadecimal words dump (32bit)
- `pxq @ rsp` - to show hexadecimal quad-words dump (64bit)
- `ad@r:SP` - to analyze the stack data

Comment: Does it mean that I have to use a command after each **step over** to get an update on stack?

Comment: No, you can use Visual Panel Mode (`v!`) -- check out my answer [here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15960/is-there-any-tool-to-visually-see-program-stack-in-linux-while-debugging/15968#15968). If you want a view similar to PEDA's you can use `e dbg.slow = true` and then use `Vpp`. That's way you'll see a Visual Mode as well as Stack Telescoping.

Comment: Thanks! though I still can't scroll through the stack. When I use the arrow keys, it scrolls the code at the bottom of the page and the stack doesn't scroll. Do you know how to scroll through stack?

Comment: In visual panel mode you can use Tab to move between the panels and h, J, k, and l to scroll inside the panel.

Comment: No I mean how to scroll in Vpp. in visual panel mode the stack is like the figure I posted. So scrolling isn't useful

Comment: You can split the Visual screen, check out my answer [here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/16468/18698).

Comment: Thanks and sorry for multiple question. But still it doesn't work properly for me: the horizontal splitting does not show both right and left sides at the same time. It just shows the code and then when I press a button, it shows the stack (for which I used one of your commands above) just for a second and again it disappears. Have you had this issue? Have you actually tested the splitting with for instance ad@r:SP ?

Comment: The way to do it was actually to enter the cursor mode with c and then tab to select stack, regs or disasm

Comment: For a shorter version of the very long output, just mention write `pxr 20r:SP`